# Add middleware to page in nuxt-typescript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i'm working on nuxt-typescript project. my middleware in /middleware/redirect.ts:

```js
import { Middleware } from '@nuxt/types'

const redirect: Middleware = (context) => {
  console.log(context)
}

export default redirect
```

and added to index.veu page like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import redirect from '~/middleware/redirect'

export default Vue.extend({
  middleware: [redirect],
  data () {
    return {}
  }
})
</script>
```

but it does not work and I get error.
any solution?

unfortunately, the documentation is not clear. [click](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/middlewares/)

Comment: Shouldn't you list used middlewares in the list as strings? Like this: `middleware: ['redirect']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to import nor give an object to it, simply pass the name as shown in the documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware#named-middleware

This should be enough

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  middleware: 'redirect',
  data () {
    return {}
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: yeahhh, worked. if this page has more than one middleware, in that case, what can I do?

Comment: Then you can totally pass an array indeed, like `middleware: ['redirect', 'other']`, but be aware that the order is important: it will be sequential. Same can be done in `nuxt.config.js`, router's key btw: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#middleware